# How to ask the user to login before proceeding into viewing profile?

Tags: android, authentication, navigationbar

how can i do this?
before he can proceed he will be ask to login, the login button will be show and if the user logged in the login button will be disappear and it will redirect to the profile and the content of that is going to change.
Please help me i need it on my project.

[Login Process before proceeding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ45F.png)
[After Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l6zI.png)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You need to be more specific as to your problem, what you have tried and show code.  As the question reads now, it is too broad.

Comment: sorry @StephenM im just new here. i didnt know.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  If you can improve your question you may receive more answers and up votes instead of down votes.  This is a site for asking and learning, so don't be too hard on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a boolean so when you are logged in you can set the menu item title to "Profile" or something else.

Try this:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
if(<<logged in>>){
    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profile).setTitle("Profile");
}
```

Comment: is that can be do at fragment?